# Using deleteRow to delete a row by id

Tags: javascript

Anyways, I'm currently doing a repeater-type of add/delete rows. Looking through the documentation, it only appears to manual delete based on row number.

Take not that this is called under a LaravelBlade foreach loop so I added respective IDs when being clicked

```
var approverCount = 0;

function add(id)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table" + id);

    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);       

    cell1.innerHTML = "Hi";
    cell2.innerHTML = "Hello";
    testCount++;
    row.id = 'teste_' + id + '_' + testCount;
}

function remove(tableId, rowId)
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
    table.deleteRow(row); 
    // stopped here due to constraints from problem
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Looking through the documentation, it only appears to manual delete based on row number."*? What documentation? The DOM? You can delete rows without IDs in the DOM. What's the actual question here?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder documentation for insertRow and deleteRow (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp)

Comment: w3schools is not "documentation," it's a meta-site with broad but flawed coverage. I suggest using specs ([here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/), [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/)) and MDN ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to delete a table row by its `id`, then it can be done purely from that one `id`, and it's fairly straightforward with `remove` (slightly modern) or [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) (universally supported):

```
// On a modern browser
document.getElementById(theRowID).remove();
```

or

```
// On slightly less modern browsers
var row = document.getElementById(theRowID);
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

If for some reason you really want to use the table's [`deleteRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow), then you'd use the row's [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex):

```
table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use row number instead of id attribute:

```
table.deleteRow(0);
```